# Is there any alternative approach to parse and render HTML text in JavaFX instead of using WebView?

Tags: javafx

Since JavaFX Label is not able to parse and render HTML content, like Swing JLabel does, the approach of using a WebView just to parse and render simple HTML texts sounds like to use a Tomahawk missile to kill a mosquito.
Anyone has alternative ideas how to parse and render simple HTML text in JavaFX, instead of using WebView?
The snippet code below shows an example using a WebView that seems too heavy and complicated.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("StackOverFlow Example");
    stage.setWidth(816);
    stage.setHeight(310);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    VBox root = new VBox();     

    HBox option1 = buildLineOption("balls", "blue", 1, 2);
    HBox option2 = buildLineOption("bikes", "red", 2, 3);
    HBox option3 = buildLineOption("bananas", "magenta", 3, 4);
    HBox option4 = buildLineOption("squares", "orange", 1, 2);
    HBox option5 = buildLineOption("lions", "yellow", 2, 4);
    HBox option6 = buildLineOption("numbers", "green", 3, 5);
    HBox option7 = buildLineOption("letters", "white", 1, 4);
    HBox option8 = buildLineOption("days", "black", 2, 5);
    HBox option9 = buildLineOption("keys", "purple", 3, 4);

    root.getChildren().addAll(option1, option2, option3, option4, option5, option6, option7, option8, option9);
    scene.setRoot(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }

  private HBox buildLineOption(String controlType, String color, int minInit, int maxInit) {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    browser.setMaxWidth(450);
    browser.setMinWidth(450);
    browser.setPrefWidth(450);
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> minValueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 5, minInit);
    SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> maxValueFactory = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 5, maxInit);
    final Spinner<Integer> minSpinner = new Spinner<Integer>();
    minSpinner.setValueFactory(minValueFactory);        
    final Spinner<Integer> maxSpinner = new Spinner<Integer>();
    maxSpinner.setValueFactory(maxValueFactory);        

    HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hBox.setPadding(new Insets(0, 5, 0, 5));
    hBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey");
    hBox.setMaxSize(800, 30);
    hBox.setMinSize(800, 30);
    hBox.setPrefSize(800, 30);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(checkBox, browser, minSpinner, maxSpinner);
    webEngine.loadContent(String.format("<html><style>body {background-color: lightgrey}</style>"
        + "Keep the quantity of <font color=%s><b>%s </b></font> <b>%s</b> between limits:</html>", color, color, controlType));

    return hBox;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use Jsoup. It's probably better if you don't need the gui.

Comment: Generally (via HTML or otherwise) there's not much support for multiple styles in text-based controls in JavaFX. Try putting `Text` instances into a `TextFlow` and giving them different styles (via CSS for example). You could also look at [RichTextFX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX), though that might be overkill for this too.

Comment: Well, like the snippet code shows, it is a GUI issue. I'm not sure, but I think JSoup will not solve the problem in this situation.

Comment: @LotoClover Yes, you are right. JSoup will not help you but you did not make it very clear in your question what you actually want to achieve. You are constantly talking about "parsing HTML" and that's what JSoup does.

Comment: @mipa, You are right, I agree, ambiguity is not good. In order to try to make the question more clear I changed the verb "to parse" to  expression "parse and render".